# Tkinter IntVar attribute error when using radiobuttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a simple calculator using tkinter, and this error message keeps showing up.

> AttributeError: type object 'Tk' has no attribute 'IntVar'

Traceback:

> File "c:/Desktop/my programs/Calculator.py", line 9, in 
> v = Tk.IntVar()
> AttributeError: type object 'Tk' has no attribute 'IntVar'

here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
tk = Tk()
v = Tk.IntVar()
v.set(1)  # initializing the choice   
root.title('Calculator')
root.geometry('600x400+50+50')
def calucator():
   value1 = tk.StringVar(root, Value= 'Number:' )
   value1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=value1).pack()
   time.sleep(1)
   value2 = tk.StringVar(root, Value= 'Number:' )
   value2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=value2).pack()
   time.sleep(1)  

   operations = [("Addition", 101),
                 ("Subtraction", 102),
                 ("Divison", 103),
                 ("Mulitplication", 104)]

   def ShowChoice():
       print(v.get())

       tk.Label(root, 
            text="""Choose your Operation""",
            justify = tk.LEFT,
            padx = 20).pack()

            for operations, val in operations:
               tk.Radiobutton(root, 
               text=operations,
               padx = 20, 
               variable=v, 
               command=ShowChoice,
               value=val).pack(anchor=tk.W)  
         

if val==101:
    print('value1 + value2')

elif val==102:
    print('value1 - value2')

elif val==103:
    print('value1 * value2')

elif val==104:
    print('value1 / value2')

else:
    close
```

I have looked everywhere and are yet to find a fix. I am aware that there are other threads on stack overflow with similar problems to mine however all the solutions I have tried have not worked.

Any help would be great!
mrt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've imported a module and named it `tk`. Then you create a new object and named it `tk`. You can only have one thing with that name.

The solution is to choose a different name for the instance of `Tk`, or choose a different name for your import.

You need to remove `tk=Tk()`. Also, `v = Tk.IntVar()` needs to be `v = tk.IntVar()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you explain how I would implement this into my code? I am new to Tkinter so I don't exactly understand what you mean.

Comment: @mrt: don't do `tk=Tk()`.